# How many ways to withdraw $k$ balls from an urn with $n$ red and $m$ blue ones?

Tags: combinatorics

An urn contains $n$ red balls and $m$ blue balls. Of how many ways can we withdrawn a total of k balls, so that  $k\le m+n$?

My friend told me that there are  $\binom {m+n}{k}$ ways to do that but for example if we have $n=m=3$ and we want to withdrawn  a total of $k=3$ balls then according to my friend it would be a total of $\binom{6}{3}=20$ ways to do that but I think that there are just 8 ways to do that since both red balls and blue balls are indistinguishable

I would really appreciate your help :)

Comment: The question needs some clarification. That you say there are 8 ways to draw three suggests you're assuming order matters. Order probably should not matter, since picking one red then two blue should be the same as picking two blues then one red, no? But given that the balls of a certain colour are all indistinguishable, you're closer than your friend is.

Answer (score 0):

If balls of the same color are indistinguishable, but the order in which they are drawn matters (i.e., we are interested in the number of distinct arrangements of $k$ balls selected from a pool of $n$ red and $m$ blue balls), then clearly, if $k \le \min(m,n)$, the total number of such arrangements is simply $2^k$.  The situation gets more interesting if $k > \min(m,n)$.  Without loss of generality, suppose $m < n$.  If $m < k \le n$, then there are insufficient blue balls to obtain arrangements with at least $m+1$ blue balls.  If $m < n < k \le m+n$, then there are insufficient balls of *both* colors, and all arrangements must contain a combination of both colors.

That's all I will provide in the way of hints.  The remainder is up to you.

Comment: thanks a lot!! heropup :) I´ll think about it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the blue balls are indistinguishable and red balls are indistinguishable, number of ways in which one can have a total of $k$ balls is the number of solutions to the equation:

$x_1+x_2=k$

Here $x_1$ is the number of red balls and $x_2$ is the number of blue balls. Clearly, you need to find the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(1+x+x^2+...+x^n)(1+x+x^2+...+x^m)$.

So this gives you the number of solutions to ($x_1,x_2$) IGNORING the order in which the balls appear while drawing. If you are interested in the order in which balls are withdrawn, then you need to put in values of $x_1$ and then carry out the combinations.

Like, if you take $0$ red balls, $x_2=k$ so now you select the places to keep your red balls in $C(k,0)=1$ way.

Put $x_1=1$ then no. of ways = $C(k,1)$. Put $x_1=2$ then no. of ways = $C(k,2)$. Go on till you have $x_1=n$ which can be done in $C(k,n)$ ways. Of course, if your $k<n$ then the coefficients become $0$ earlier. After you have taken out all your $n$ red balls, since your $k$ is fixed, and $n$ is also fixed, $x_2=k-n$ will be fixed, implying that henceforth, all selections will be $C(k,n)$.

So total number of ways INCLUDING ordering = $C(k,0)+C(k,1)+C(k,2)+...+C(k,n)$

Comment: You can use **bold** for emphasis, it looks better than ALL CAPS. Double asterisks for `**bold**`, single asterisks for `*italic*`.